# applying the same function twice

Tags: r, list, subset

How can I apply the same function twice? 
Fo example instead of

```
lapply(1:10,function(i)lapply(1:10,function(i) a.root(c,i))[[i]]$aj)
```

can I use only one function?

Comment: Do you mean recursively? the same function inside the function? What's the purpose?

Comment: With the innermost lapply I get my roots: 10 lists with two elemets. With the second lapply I get only the first element .

Comment: Would be great to help you if some reproducible example or your input data is provided.